# Concatenate csv files with condition

Tags: python, pandas, csv, concatenation

I would like to concatenate a number of csv files with a condition on the value of a column in the fastest way possible.

I have some code that works, however it concatenates all the lines of all the csv files before i reduce the dataframe down to the stations i need (through value in the `station_number` column). I would like to select the rows I need first, before doing the concatenation, so it would improve the running time.    Thank you for any suggestion!

```
station = int(input("station number? ")) 

def Datastations (station,path): 
    filepaths = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in listdir(path) if f.endswith('.csv')]
    df = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, filepaths)) 
    df = df[df.station_number==station]
    return (df)

df1 = Datastations(station,"refdata/obs") 
df2 = Datastations(station,"refdata/BoM_ETA_20160501-20170430/obs")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say what you were having trouble with, so I can only reorder this for you:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def Datastations (station,path): 
    filepaths = [os.path.join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.csv')]
    def process_csv(file_name):
        df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
        return df[df.station_number==station]
    return pd.concat(map(process_csv, filepaths))
```